# Change the permission of package info on system app

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, permission

I am trying to change the sound of the PowerChime.app(/System/Library/CoreServices), when i plug in the charging cable. That means that i need to swap out the `/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif`. but I do not have permission to. I have tried `sudo chmod 777 /` and `sudo chown [user] Resources`, that gives me a `Operation not permitted`. What can i do?

Comment: You would need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

Comment: @red_menace How do i do that?

Comment: I did disable it in recovery mode, but i stil do not have permission to change it. When in the terminal i type `csrutil status` it responds with `System Integrity Protection status: disabled.` I dont get why I still can't edit the dir.